# Does the operator [] accepts types other than ints in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

I'm trying to recreate the `Dictionary` from python into C++, for the sake of learning.

I want to be able to use the subscript operator [] with a `keyType` (which is the data type of the keys in the dictionary, might be an int, string... etc), I tried this approach (i'm using linked lists):

```
    // keyFind is the value to be found
    void operator[](keyType keyFind) {
        typeList* trav; // typeList is an alias for: linked_list<keyType, valType>
        for (trav = head; trav != nullptr; trav = trav->next) {
            if (trav->key == keyFind) {
                cout << trav->val << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `void` return type is a place holder for a future return type.

My question is: Should I use this approach or should I simply use a normal function instead, which one is considered **Best Practise** ?

Comment: take a look at how the standard library does it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at So yes, it's a good ideea to accept the key type as parameter.

Comment: I would recomend the aproach of @bolov. Im not sure if it is a "*Best Practise*", but it surely be familiar to other people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the operator [] accepts types other than ints in C++?

Operator overloads are just functions, and they can accept any parameter types just as other functions can. So, yes.

The C++ standard library already provides `std::unordered_map` and `std::map` which are for most purposes analogous to Python dictionaries.

Comment: I think "operator overloads are just functions" is a little bit reductive. For instance, you can't write an overload of `operator[]` with a signature that accepts multiple arguments.